# Error compiling Web app using GWT in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I am following a [tutorial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/usingeclipse.html) to make a very simple demo app using GWT with eclipse ee.
I created a Web Application using steps: select File > New > Web Application Project. From the Eclipse menu, accepted defaults, unchecked use Google App Engine SDK & Generate GWT project sample code. Run it by Debug As > Web Application. It raises this error:

*Missing required argument 'module[s]'
Google Web Toolkit 2.2.0
..................................................................................................................................................................
and 
module[s]        Specifies the name(s) of the module(s) to host*

Comment: That tutorial works perfectly ... you might want to try again.

Comment: ... don't uncheck the option "Generate GWT project sample code"!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to generate sample code, you have to create the gwt xml module (MyProject.gwt.xml), because eclipse doesn't generate this automatically.

Comment: I have the default gwt.xml file in the web folder, still i get the error.